# Ficar no Loop até o valor digitado ser negativo

Tags: python-3.x

Elabore um programa que faça a leitura de vários números inteiros, até que se digite um número negativo. O programa tem que retornar o menor e o maior número lido.

Tentei fazer, porém na hora de mostrar o menor número lido sempre está aparecendo o 0.

```
maior = menor = valor = i = 0
print('Digite números inteiros! Um número menor que zero para o programa!')
while valor >= 0:
    valor = int(input(f'Digite o {i + 1}° valor: '))
    if valor > maior:
        maior = valor
    if (valor < menor) and (valor >= 0):
        menor = valor
    i += 1
print(maior)
print(menor)
```

Comment: Se o valor tem que ser >= 0 e você coloca como valor inicial zero então nenhum valor informado será menor que este valor inicial. Tente colocar o maior número possível de ser representado neste tipo de dado.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Inicialize com um numero grande o menor, 0 sempre será o menor nos naturais

Answer (score -3):

Aparentemente, quanto a condição fica (valor>=0), ele não atualizar, porém ao retira-lo, ele identificará um novo valor, no caso um negativo.

maior = menor = valor = i = 0

print('Digite números inteiros! Um número menor que zero para o programa!')

while valor >= 0:

```
valor = int(input(f'Digite o {i + 1}° valor: '))

if valor > maior:
    maior = valor

if (valor < menor): #and (valor >= 0):

    menor = valor

i += 1
```

print(maior)

print(menor)